# skip tables when running Doctrine convert-mapping

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm sitting down with doctrine for the first time and trying to use some of it's command line tools on an existing site/database. I've played with the mapping and entity reverse-engineering tools from the command line and wanted to see what kind of files it would generate from an existing website in php/mysql.

However, it stops on any Exceptions. I was already able to create a type mapping for enum to just throw them to a string for now, but now it's stopping me on tables that do not have a primary ID key specified. I'm not interested in a lecture on using primary keys or compound keys in link tables, I'm just trying to generate some output while learning Doctrine at the moment.

Is there a way to either tell doctrine to skip tables that are throwing exceptions or to barrel through without stopping when it hits them? I just want some sample output at the moment and don't want to entirely re-factor a complex database just to see what Doctrine can do.

SW

Comment: It is far easier to create a new application that adheres to the doctrine specifications than adapt an existing application. Even more so with a full-stack framework such as Symfony 2. I recommend starting from scratch, with something simplistic, to see how it all works. Start off with a basic table and it's CRUD. Followed by a one to many association, then many to many associations and their CRUDs. Then use what you learn to convert an existing application. You really shouldn't try to force doctrine to work around issues it has with an existing application, it may break/corrupt it.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with Doctrine's conversion and validation is that it reads the entire database and all tables by default, regardless of the Entities or Mappings for them existing or not. Even when using the `--filter=""` flag when calling `orm:convert:mapping` or `orm:generate:entities`

To get around this issue and to have Doctrine skip tables that throw Exceptions, you can set Doctrine to only read the tables you want, by defining them with `setFilterSchemaAssetsExpression`

```
$isDev = true;

$config = \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array('/path/to/entities'), $isDev);
$config->setFilterSchemaAssetsExpression('/^(table1|table2|prefixed_.*|.*_suffixed)$/');

$em =  \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create(array(
    'driver' => 'db_driver',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'user_name',
    'password' => 'user_password',
    'dbname' => 'database',
), $config);
```

OR you can set the filter for the connection of an existing Entity manager.

```
$em->getConnection()->setFilterSchemaAssetsExpression('/^(filtered_table)$/');
```

Reference: 
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html

Granted this isn't a way to tell doctrine to ignore exceptions, but should help you to get started with learning on an existing application on some specific tables instead of the entire database.

---

As a side-note since you mentioned you have link tables.
If you have foreign keys in tables that you do not include in the filter, the   --from-database conversion will still create a reference for it.
You will have to manually change the mapping to it's raw form rather than it's associated mapping of OneToMany, ManyToOne or ManyToMany.

Annotation Mapping From `doctrine orm:convert:mapping --from-database annotation /path/to/entities`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="order")
 */
class Order
{
  /** 
   * @var \Customer
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
   * })
   */
   private customer;
}
```

To

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="order")
 */
class Order
{
  /** 
   * @var integer
   * @ORM\Column(name="customer", type="integer", nullable=true)
   */
   private customer;
}
```

Then don't forget to use `doctrine orm:validate-schema` to ensure that the mappings are in sync.

Answer (score 3):

Revisiting this same issue again. What I found that seems to work was using filtering in the cli configuration via the bootstrap file:

```
// bootstrap.php
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$site_root = realpath(__DIR__ . "/../");

$paths = [ $site_root . "/libraries/Doctrine/Entities" ];
$isDevMode = false;

// used when building entities from database using command line tool
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);

$filter_include = [
    'some_table_name',
    'another_table_name',
    '.*some_sub_portion.*',
    '^some_table_prefix_.*',
    '.*some_table_suffix$'
];
$include_reg = '/^(' . implode('|', $filter_include) . ').*$/';

$filter_exclude = [
    // tables with no primary key generate exceptions
    'some_table_name',
    'another_table_name',
    '.*some_sub_portion.*',
    '^some_table_prefix_.*',
    '.*some_table_suffix$'
];
$exclude_reg = '/^(?!(?:' . implode('|', $filter_exclude) . ')$).*$/';

// use include list
//$config->setFilterSchemaAssetsExpression($include_reg);
// use exclude list
$config->setFilterSchemaAssetsExpression($exclude_reg);

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'myuser',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'dbname'   => 'mydatabase',
);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

$platform = $entityManager->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
$platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue a while ago. Exactly in the same order. First I had to map the enum to string and then it complained about the missing primary keys.

I'm quite sure there is no way to ignore the exceptions. Or at least I couldn't find one either in the docs or online.
So what I did was to add a primary key for all the tables that didn't have one. Like
alter table  add temp_id int primary key not null auto_increment;

And then I started off from there to see which entities to keep and which ones to drop.
Otherwise you could make a copy of the db and drop the tables without primary key.
But if the db has a lot of tables it might take a while by hand, and you should to look into making a procedure